# SwiftUI persist observable objects

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to understand data flows in swiftUI.

I have created a ViewModel which holds some data from a network request.

```
import SwiftUI

struct breakdown: Decodable {
    var sms: Int
    var im: Int
    var total: Int
}

struct weeklyOverviewStruct: Decodable {
    var data: [breakdown]
}

class WeeklyOverviewViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var overviewData: weeklyOverviewStruct?

    func getBreakdown(){

        semaphore.wait()

              Network.Request(method: .GET , parameters: nil, endPoint: "rest/operator/stats/weekly/breakdown", completion: {
                         result,error  in

                         if(error == nil){

                          do {
                              let breakdown = try JSONDecoder().decode(weeklyOverviewStruct.self, from: result!)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                self.overviewData = breakdown

                            }

                          }catch{
                              print("Json Error")
                          }
                         }else{
                             print("\(error!)")
                         }
                     })
    }

}
```

It my understanding that I can then observe this ViewModel in a second view and the view will re-draw if the ViewModel changes:

```
struct SecondView: View {

     @ObservedObject var WeeklyOverviewVM = WeeklyOverviewViewModel()

       var body: some View {
        Text(String.init(describing: WeeklyOverviewVM.overviewData?.data[0].total))
    }
}
```

If however the second view is presented after the getBreakDown() is called the observedObject is nil.

Is there a way of persisting the data so that even if a view is presented after the getBreakdown() function is called, the data from the previous request is observable in the second view?

Comment: You could also use Environment...This helped me a lot understanding SwiftUI/Bindings https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SecondView` now creates view model every time it is instantiated, so if you want previously fetched data persist, it needs to store that view model instance somewhere outside of `SecondView` and inject it on its creation, like

```
struct SecondView: View {
     // only declare
     @ObservedObject var WeeklyOverviewVM: WeeklyOverviewViewModel
```

and somewhere in parent view

```
    ...
    // inject WeeklyOverviewViewModel from own property
    SecondView(WeeklyOverviewVM: self.secondViewVM)
    ...
```